# i need an excel formula for returning a rank value in a table for a group of values, corresponding to multiple criteria in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following data in columns A to D.
I need the formula for as to return the value mentioned in column E.

```
Date  Session  IngredientName  Qty  SessionRank
01-Mar-24   Breakfast   Salt    2.5 2
01-Mar-24   Breakfast   Sugar   2   3
01-Mar-24   Breakfast   Mirchi Powder   0.5 4
01-Mar-24   Breakfast   Rawa    5   1
01-Mar-24   Lunch   Salt    2.5 2
01-Mar-24   Lunch   Sugar   2   3
01-Mar-24   Lunch   Mirchi Powder   0.5 4
01-Mar-24   Lunch   Rawa    5   1
01-Mar-24   Dinner  Salt    2.5 1
01-Mar-24   Dinner  Sugar   2   2
01-Mar-24   Dinner  Mirchi Powder   0.5 3
02-Mar-24   Breakfast   Salt    2.5 1
02-Mar-24   Breakfast   Sugar   2   2
02-Mar-24   Breakfast   Mirchi Powder   0.5 3
02-Mar-24   Lunch   Rawa    5   1
02-Mar-24   Lunch   Salt    2.5 2
02-Mar-24   Lunch   Sugar   2   3
02-Mar-24   Lunch   Mirchi Powder   0.5 5
02-Mar-24   Dinner  Salt    2.5 2
02-Mar-24   Dinner  Sugar   2   3
02-Mar-24   Dinner  Mirchi Powder   0.5 4
02-Mar-24   Dinner  Rawa    5   1
```

I tried to use the below formulae.

```
=RANK.EQ([@Qty], FILTER(Table1, [@Date]=Table1[Date], [@Session]=Table1[Session]), 0)

=RANK.EQ([@Qty], FILTER(Table1, ([@Date]=Table1[Date]) * ([@Session]=Table1[Session])), 0)
```

Both the formulae are returning errors.

Kindly help.

Regards
Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
=COUNTIFS([Date],[@Date],[Qty],">"&[@Qty])+1
```

If you have any other approach, let us know.